# Finding a sequence $\{e_n\}$ of continuous functions such that $0 \leq e_n (x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in X$ and $\text {supp}\ (e_n) \subseteq K_{n+1}.$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> Let $X$ be a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. Then does there exist a sequence $\{e_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ of continuous functions on $X$ such that the following conditions hold $:$
>
> $(1)$ $X = \bigcup\limits_{n \geq 1} K_n$ where each $K_n$ is compact and $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1.$
>
> $(2)$ For any compact set $K \subseteq X$ there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $K \subseteq K_m$ and hence $K \subseteq K_n$ for all $n \geq m.$
>
> $(3)$ $0 \leq e_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in X.$
>
> $(4)$ $e_n (x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_n.$
>
> $(5)$ $\text {supp}\ (e_n) \subseteq K_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1.$

$(1)$ follows from $\sigma$-compactness of $X$ and from the fact that union of finitely many compact sets is again compact. But I have no idea for the rest three. Could anyone give me some suggestion in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't $e_n \equiv 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @angryvian$:$ Sorry, I have missed one criterion. Adding it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you want to construct $K_n$ or is it given?

Comment: @Arctic Char$:$ I have to construct $K_n$'s also. In case when $X = \mathbb R$ we can simply take $K_n = [-n,n]$ for all $n \geq 1.$ But how can I construct them for the general case?

Comment: That can be found in Lee's introduction to smooth manifold, when they construct partition of unity. In their construction they have $M = \cup U_j$, $U_1\subset \cdots \subset U_j \subset\cdots$ and $\overline{U_i}$ is compactly contained in $U_{i+1}$. Then $K_i = \overline {U_i}$ is what you want. The existence of $e_j$'s are consequence of Urysohn's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the background results needed are stated and proved in Section 4.5 of [Folland (1999, pp. 131–136)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166). The references below correspond to the enumeration in that book.

> **Proposition 4.39** There is a sequence $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of open sets such that
>
> - $\overline{U_n}$ (the closure of $U_n$) is compact for each $n\in\mathbb N$;
> - $\overline{U_n}\subseteq U_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$; and
> - $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} U_n$.

Define $K_n\equiv\overline{U_n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Clearly,

(1) $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n$ and $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Let $K\subseteq X$ be a compact set. Then, $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a nested open cover of $K$, so there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $K\subseteq U_n\subseteq \overline{U_n}=K_n$. This gives you (2).

> **Lemma 4.32 (Urysohn, locally compact version)** If $K\subseteq U\subseteq X$, where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open, then there exists a continuous $e:X\to[0,1]$ such that
>
> - $e(x)=1$ for each $x\in K$; and
> - $e$ vanishes outside a compact subset of $U$.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, $K_n\subseteq U_{n+1}\subseteq X$, where $K_n$ is compact and $U_{n+1}$ is open. You can find

(3) a continuous function $e_n:X\to[0,1]$

such that

(4) $e_n(x)=1$ for each $x\in K_n$,

and a compact set $C_n\subseteq U_{n+1}$ such that $e_n(x)=0$ whenever $x\in X\setminus C_n$. This means that

(5) $\operatorname{supp}e_n\subseteq C_n\subseteq U_{n+1}\subseteq\overline{U_{n+1}}=K_{n+1}$.